# Umbraco UComment in IIS7 Application (Not Default Web Site)

Tags: comments, umbraco, gravatar

I recently installed Umbraco 4.5.2 into an IIS application, not as the default web site.  The main Umbraco CMS seems to work as expected, I can add and remove content, and all kinds of other wonderful things.  However, when I'm trying to use the UComment module, it can't seem to locate the following two resources:

/base/UComment/GetGravatarImage//80.aspx
/base/UComment/CreateComment/.aspx

I wonder if anyone else has run into this issue before, or even attempted to do what I'm doing before.  Any sort of guidance on this one would be great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the /base extensions weren't installed correctly. Add this to your config/restExtensions.config:

```
  <ext assembly="bin/UComment" type="UComment.Library.Base" alias="UComment">
    <permission method="CreateComment" returnXml="false" allowAll="true" />
    <permission method="GetGravatarImage" returnXml="false" allowAll="true" />
  </ext>
```

Comment: It was missing the "bin" in the assembly attribute.  Thanks!

Comment: OK, even after adding the "bin" in the assembly attribute, it doesn't seem able to find base/UComment/GetGravatarImage/youremail@domain.com/80.aspx.  I imagine I'm just missing something either in the JavaScript in the user control or in a config somewhere, and ideas?